# If the saturation point of saltwater is 26%, why aren't oceans getting saltier over time?

Tags: oceanography

From what I read they've been at 3.5% salt equilibrium for millions of years. How is this possible when rivers are constantly flowing dissolving salt into them?

Comment: Related if not duplicate: https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/20432/18081

Answer (score 4):

Because salt gets buried over time. Most of the salt we mine is old seas / oceans that dried up and then got buried. Subduction zones carry salt-laden and water-laden sediments very deep underground. The water tends to escape by volcanism. The salt does not.

Comment: So the ocean gets less deep over time? Because the ocean floor is getting higher with the salt buildup and formation of new surface

Comment: @Groveish Google "subduction zone". The continents are in general much older than are the oceans. The oldest continental crust is over 3 billion years old. The oldest ocean crust is less than 200 million years old.